# median of panda datetime64 column

Tags: python, python-datetime, datetime64

Is there a way to compute and return in datetime format the median of a datetime column?
I want to calculate the median of a column in python which is in datetime64[ns] format. Below is a sample to the column:

```
df['date'].head()

0   2017-05-08 13:25:13.342
1   2017-05-08 16:37:45.545
2   2017-01-12 11:08:04.021
3   2016-12-01 09:06:29.912
4   2016-06-08 03:16:40.422
```

Name: recency, dtype: datetime64[ns]

My aim is to have the median in same datetime format as the date column above:

Tried converting to np.array:

```
median_ = np.median(np.array(df['date']))
```

But that throws the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Converting to int64 and then calculating the median and attempt to the return format to datetime does not work

```
df['date'].astype('int64').median().astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just taking the middle value?

```
dates = list(df.sort('date')['date'])
print dates[len(dates)//2]
```

If the table is sorted you can even skip a line.

Comment: Thanks @kabanus. This works well. It did not occur to me to sort and use the length of the column.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try [`quantile(0.5)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```py
df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').quantile(0.5, interpolation="midpoint")
```

Answer (score 4):

You are close, the `median()` return a `float` so convert it to be an `int` first:

```
import math

median = math.floor(df['date'].astype('int64').median())
```

Then convert the `int` represent the date into `datetime64`:

```
result = np.datetime64(median, "ns") #unit: nanosecond
```