Numpy: UFuncBinaryResolutionError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[D]') and dtype('<M8[D]')
One of my function generates list of dates in numpy array like so and iam just trying to apply median function on results...Finding median in such arrays is invalid or Iam missing something??
Reproducable
import numpy as np
dt_array = np.array([np.datetime64('2024-08-16'), np.datetime64('2024-08-15')]) #dt_array  = ['2024-08-16' '2024-08-15']
np.median(dt_array)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACENTAURI-1009\Desktop\pdf.py", line 5, in <module>
    np.median(dt_array)
  File "C:\Users\ACENTAURI-1009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3927, in median
    return _ureduce(dt_array, func=_median, keepdims=keepdims, axis=axis, out=out,
  File "C:\Users\ACENTAURI-1009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3823, in _ureduce
    r = func(dt_array , **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACENTAURI-1009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3979, in _median
    rout = mean(part[indexer], axis=axis, out=out)
  File "C:\Users\ACENTAURI-1009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3504, in mean
    return _methods._mean(dt_array, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
  File "C:\Users\ACENTAURI-1009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 118, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where=where)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncBinaryResolutionError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[D]') and dtype('<M8[D]')


A similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889611/median-of-panda-datetime64-column

NumPy supports some operations like subtraction between datetime objects (which results in timedelta64) but it doesn't support addition or averaging which is required for finding the median.
import numpy as np
dt_array = np.array([np.datetime64('2024-08-16'), np.datetime64('2024-08-15')])

#this converts the day time to only days from the epoch which is january 1 , 1970 . The for this the value of jan 1 , 1970 is = 0

int_array = dt_array.astype('int64') 
median_int = np.median(int_array)

# Now calculate the median
median_date = np.datetime64(int(median_int), 'D')

print(median_date)


One way can be:
import numpy as np
dt_array = np.array([np.datetime64('2024-08-16'), np.datetime64('2024-08-15')]) 

#array(['2024-08-16', '2024-08-15'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

Convert datetime[D] into nanoseconds:
timestamps = dt_array.astype('datetime64[ns]').astype('int64')

#array([1723766400000000000, 1723680000000000000], dtype=int64)

Take median with numpy
median_timestamp = np.median(timestamps)

#1.7237232e+18

Convert it back
median_timestamp.astype('datetime64[ns]')

#numpy.datetime64('2024-08-15T12:00:00.000000000')


This works... I have created a function which converts into nanosec before median ..+1
